# PHP - MySQLi Prepared Statement: unknown "max" function (Error 1630)

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I get an error when preparing a simple statement to be queried on my database. It's a quite simple one. Allegedly the function `max()` does not exist. This ist the simple query:

```
SELECT coalesce ( max ( p_order ), 0 ) + 1 AS new FROM pages
```

It has no parameters to be bound (but I use an own class for managing my queries so prepared statements are always used).

When preparing the statement I get the following error from the Database: "FUNCTION fa_cms.max does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual". The Code is 1630.

I can execute this query directly on the database (MariaDB 10.1.29) without any problem - and get "1" becaus the table is still empty.

But when I call this statement via my own PHP class I get this error. All other statements are prepared and executed without any problems - with or without params.

Is there anything special with the `max()` aggregate function?

Comment: Get rid of the space between `max` and `(`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N `new` is a keyword.

Comment: @MartinZeitler No it isn't. It's a keyword, but not reserved. There's no `(R)` after it.

Comment: @Barmar when only binding the statement fails, it nevertheless might be the column-name, which might require back-ticks `\`new\`` - or even a proper name.

Comment: If it needed backticks it would need them all the time, not just when binding. My guess is that he used different spacing when he ran the query manually from when he put it in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the space between `max` and `(`. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions.html):

> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen to have the same name as a function.

This requirement doesn't seem to be enforced consistently, though. It seems to only really matter when using aggregation functions.

So change your query to:

```
SELECT coalesce(max(p_order), 0) + 1 AS new FROM pages
```